# Learning Resources for Windows Server 2008 DNS

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

I don't know mush about DNS Manager in windows server 2008 r2. what is the best Learning Resources for Windows Server 2008 DNS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One place to start is the [DNS Server Operations Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816603%28WS.10%29.aspx) and the [DNS Server Help](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730921.aspx) on Microsoft Technet.  The various DNS Manager functions are documented against the tasks that they form a part of.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking at the Microsoft Technet Site, it will outline the changes to the DNS Service in Windows Server 2008 R2.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378952%28WS.10%29.aspx

Once you have done this the best learning resource I can suggest is spinning up a test server and having a play with it and it's features - from there you will be able to raise more specific queries that you need answered.

Comment: I don't need to know what is changed firstly. I haven't used DNS Manager at all :s